# Pact-broker release schedule

Tags: pact-broker

I have been looking for a defined release schedule for Pact-broker. I noticed monthly updates on the Pact sight but cannot find one hub for any upgrade schedule.

This is the most I could find on anything regarding upgrades: https://docs.pact.io/blog